# Is there a way to get public key using web3.js?

Tags: web3js, public-key

I know there are ways to get public key from private key using other then web3js tools ([EthereumJS: How to get public key from private key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/ethereumjs-how-to-get-public-key-from-private-key) and https://kobl.one/blog/create-full-ethereum-keypair-and-address/)
Also, there is a way to get public key from address having a transaction sent from that address – [Get public key of any ethereum account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account/13892)

I am looking for a way to get public key using web3js. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What data you have? If you have the private key the first question should be good, if you have a signed transaction the second is correct. If you have the UTC or JSON file you canuse the first after loading the file with a wallet.

Comment: I have all of them, but I cannot find a way to get public key using web3.js only.

Comment: I'm afraid that both versions of web3 (v0.20 and v1.0) do not expose the public key, only the private key and the address. You will need a third party library like [ethereumjs-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet) that implements a `getPublicKey()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can retrieve public key given you have a private key using web3js [web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount)

Comment: The documentation doesn't show a way to get the public key only the address and private key.