# Generating an Ethereum wallet with an existing private key

Tags: javascript, private-key

I want to understand how Ethereum works and i want to calculate the public key and wallet address from private key.

I have read this tutorial: https://piyopiyo.medium.com/generating-an-ethereum-wallet-with-an-existing-private-key-5cda690a8eb8

Here is the code:

```
var Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var EthUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
const privateKeyString = '0x...MyPrivateKey...';
const privateKeyBuffer = EthUtil.toBuffer(privateKeyString);
const wallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer);
const publicKey = wallet.getPublicKeyString();
console.log(publicKey);
const address = wallet.getAddressString();
console.log(address);
```

It sounds great but i have this runtime error:

> TypeError: Wallet.fromPrivateKey is not a function

I think this is because ethereumjs-wallet has changed in the latest versions.
But how can i load a private key with latest version ?

Thanks

Comment: `const wallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer);` generates "TypeError: Wallet.fromPrivateKey is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const wallet = Wallet['default'].fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer);`

replace this in line5

```
var Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var EthUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
const privateKeyString = '0x...MyPrivateKey...';//your privateKey
const privateKeyBuffer = EthUtil.toBuffer(privateKeyString);
const wallet = Wallet['default'].fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer);
const publicKey = wallet.getPublicKeyString();
console.log(publicKey);
const address = wallet.getAddressString();
console.log(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ethereumjs-wallet` doesn´t have a default export. You can import `Wallet` like this in Node.js:

```js
const { Wallet } = require('ethereumjs-wallet')
```

You can find the docs here: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet#wallet-api

Comment: This time i get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromPrivateKey' of undefined"

Comment: it's wrong.  there is no `Wallet` element exported.  if you look at it, it's called "default"